# Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.Form is undefined error in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular7

When I am trying to call one .ts file from another using  .Form the following error is occurring

> Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.Form is undefined

The file that has an error in it

have imported the .ts file to which i want to pass value from this file

```
import { SawtoothService } from '../sawtooth.service';
```

Declared Form using a constructor

**constructor ( private Form : SawtoothService ) {}**

The Function in which another component file function is called

```
  async addForm() {

     const proc ="VRT"
     const action ="add"
     const FAMILYNAME = 'abc' 
     const servDt =await this.Form.sendData(this.Gender,this.idproof,this.date,this.firstName,proc,action,FAMILYNAME)
     this.servicedata="this is service data"+servDt;
     alert('SUCCESS!! :-)\n\n' + this.servicedata)   
  }
```

there is a function sendData in sawtooth.service.ts file i want to pass data from this file to that file

Comment: Include the constructor of this class in your code

Comment: @IkechukwuEze added

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how `addForm` is called, it could be the matter of `this` context. Try converting it to an async arrow function:

```
  addform = async () => {
```

Comment: this.addForm()  This is how i have called the addForm()

Answer (score 0):

```
    const servDt = await 
 this.Form.sendData(this.Gender,this.idproof,this.date,this.firstName,proc,action,FAMILYNAME)
```

should be

```
    const servDt = await this.SawtoothService.sendData(this.Gender,this.idproof,this.date,this.firstName,proc,action,FAMILYNAME)
```

Even though I can't see the rest of the code in this present file. Normally you'd inject the service in your constructor, then you can then call `this.name_of_service.any_method_you_created_on_it`